# Consulta sql, obtener último registro

Tags: oracle-11g

Tengo la siguiente consulta. ¿Cómo obtengo el último registro, ya que `ct_contrato_cuenta`, obtiene dos registros cuando hace el `join` con `ct_factura`

```
SELECT  *
FROM ct_contrato_cuenta,ct_factura
WHERE ct_contrato_cuenta.n_id_factura = ct_factura.n_id
and ct_factura.n_id = 23000
```

Comment: puedes usar un order by fecha o algo que te de la antiguedad o tambien si los dos resultados son iguales utiliza el limit 1

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo funcional, yo utilizaria tu consulta pero tal que así

```
    SELECT count(*)
FROM ct_contrato_cuenta,ct_factura
WHERE ct_contrato_cuenta.n_id_factura = ct_factura.n_id
and ct_factura.n_id = 23000
```

De esta forma primero obtendrás el número de registros que tendrá esta consulta y luego cuando tenga este número que imagino que podrá variar, volvería a relizar la misma consulta pero así.

```
SELECT  *
FROM ct_contrato_cuenta,ct_factura
WHERE ct_contrato_cuenta.n_id_factura = ct_factura.n_id
and ct_factura.n_id = 23000 and "INDICE DE LA TABLA" = "VALOR OBTENIDO ANTERIOR POR LA FUNCION COUNT()"
```

Otra solución si quieres evitarte otra consulta a la bbd sería guardar el resultado de la consulta count() en una variable y, utilizarlo posteriormente para buscar la posición en la lista o arrays donde recojas los datos, dependiendo del lenguaje que trabajes en el servidor se trata de una manera o de otra.

Espero te sirva un saludo.